# Test COM DLL without exporting methods explicitly

Tags: c++, com, googletest, atl

I created an ATL COM DLL. I now have to unit test the methods defined in the COM interface of the DLL. I created a console application "tester.exe" and wrote some google tests, which would talk to the COM DLL and its method. Problem is, the tester.exe only compiles if I explicitly export the COM method like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) STDMETHOD(Add)(DOUBLE Input1, DOUBLE Input2, DOUBLE* pOutput);
```

I want to test the COM interface directly and not rely on a DLL export. Is there any way my tester/com client can compile and run the dll without needing the dllexport, such that the method definition stays:

```
STDMETHOD(Add)(DOUBLE Input1, DOUBLE Input2, DOUBLE* pOutput);
```

Am I missing something very obvious? I tried looking at many resources and tutorials but none were very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing COM? COM has nothing to do with dll exports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-technical-overview

Comment: @SimonMourier yeah I am able to call into the COM DLL with a javascript library. Can I similarly call into the COM DLL with C++ console application, without requiring DLL exports?

Comment: No, a COM DLL is exposed as COM objects (and javascript can talk to objects), there's no export. You can add a "flat" API to your DLL, wrapping internally COM objects, but you cannot call a standard COM object from dll import.

Comment: That's interesting. Just to be clear, JavaScript can directly talk to a COM object but C++ console application cannot?

Comment: COM is at its roots binary contracts (vtable) plus other services (registration, marshaling, etc.). C++ console application can talk to any COM object, but not though dll imports, using COM calls (CoCreateInstance, etc.). Javascript can only call a subset of COM objects, objects that support COM Automation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/automation. COM Automation was originally invented to enable VB to use binary components written in any language. It's also well suited for scriping languages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by directly setting the CLSID and IDD in the test class:

```
const CLSID CLSID_CTest = { 0x809a77g7,0x2624,0x453e,{0xb3,0xc6,0x2c,0x68,0x15,0xff,0xe3,0x23} };
const IID IID_ICTest = { 0x0c832b41,0xbfe9,0x4a16,{0xb9,0x34,0xff,0x7f,0x8b,0x77,0x30,0x44} };
```

and then using these to create a CoCreateInstance

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTest , NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICTest , (LPVOID*)&ptrICTest);
```

With this, I neither need the lib of the COM server when compiling, nor any header.